# How many ways to split dataset into k groups of size n when order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics

I have the following set: $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$$
I want to split this set into two equal groups (e.g group of 5) and I have been asked how many ways are there to split this set when the order doesn't matter (e.g if group $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is the same case as $\{5,4,3,2,1\}$.

I think the beginning  of the answer is to $2^{10}$  for the number of options but then in order to reduce the cases where only the spot of each elemnt is different I got confused and not sure that this is the way.

I'm very beginner with this so might be that also the $2^{10}$ is wrong.

So my wurstion is  how can I calculate the number of ways to split this set into 2 groups without taking into accound the order of elemnts?

**Edit:** it does not matter which of the subsets is the first and which is the second

Comment: Have you heard of binomial coefficients?  How about multinomial coefficients?  Are your subsets you are splitting into labeled?  (*In other words, do you consider splitting into $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ to be the same or different as splitting into $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$?*)

Comment: As an aside, $2^{10}$ here represents the number of ways to split the elements into two groups where you don't care about the sizes of the groups being equal, order within each group doesn't matter, you consider the groups labeled (*a clear group A vs group B*), and you allow the groups to be empty.

Comment: I am at the very begining ans still haven't learnt about binomial coefficients,but in the question I was given it says that it does not matter, which of the subsets is the first and which is the second, i'll add it to the post

Comment: Try doing $\{1,2,3,4\}$ first. The answer you want is $$ \frac{1}{2} \binom{10}{5}=\color{red}{126}$$

Comment: The answer will be expressed using [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and/or multinomial coefficients.  Go learn about those first and then revisit this problem.  I would not have asked a student who has not learned about binomial coefficients yet this problem.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit to avoid division by symmetry, it may be better described as $\binom{9}{4}=126$, by "*choosing which four other elements appear in the group that contained $1$*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks you to select 5 random numbers in one group and the remaining 5 in the other group. For selecting the first 5 elements, we use combinatorics:

no. of ways of selecting first 5 numbers = 10C5 = 252

and for the remaining 5 numbers no. of ways = 5C5 = 1

final answer = (252*1)/2 = 126

(this is because : {1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10} is the same as {6,7,8,9,10},{1,2,3,4,5})